# Adding a List to Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I am learning Android by modifying examples. I am currently working on [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) example. What is different in my code is that I want to display the listView in a fragment.

Code (errors are shown in comments):

```
public class MovieListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = MovieListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String url = "http://example/json/movies.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                        ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //cannot resolve method findViewById(?) and cannot resolve symbol list
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
    //cannot resolve getActionBar
```

...

```
@Override
//method does not override method from its superclass 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   //cannot resolve method getMenuInflater() and cannot resolve symbol menu
    return true;
}
```

Here I have the following errors:

1. cannot resolve method ***findViewById(?)***
2. cannot resolve symbol ***list***
3. cannot resolve ***getActionBar***
4. method does not override method from its superclass
5. cannot resolve method ***getMenuInflater()***
6. cannot resolve symbol ***menu***
7. customlistadapter (android.app.activity list) in customlistadapter cannot be applied to (android.content.context)
8. in pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); ProgressDialog(android.app.activity list) in ProgressDialogcannot be applied to (com.kemo.editedtutorial.sliderfragments.MoviesListFragment)

Comment: did u downloaded the project..?

Comment: @Saravana Kumar Chinnaraj No, I typed and modified it.

Comment: its ravi's old tutorial. I recommend to follow some updated one..  also u have issue with your fragment implementation please check it properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly from your **oncreateview()** you are returning your view so, instead use

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
```

then use this view to make use of layout elements as `view.findViewById()` instead of `findViewById()` and then finally at the end return this `view`

About error *cannot resolve symbol **list***
Make sure that you have a listview defined in your layout **fragment_movies** which has id as  `android:id="@+id/list"`

The **getActionBar** thing you will do in the activity which has this fragment.
If you are using support library then you can change the actionbar drawable as

```
((YourParentActivity which has this fragment)(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));  
e.g ((MainActivity)(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
```

You can do as follows to avoid inspection error around the `getsupportActionbar`:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar!=null) {
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        }
```

If you wish to use option menus from the fragment, then in your onCreate() of fragment, add `setHasOptionMenu(true)` line. This will access your Activity's option menu.
Then to use the option menu you have to write

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

The menu will be of your android Activity, use that menu to perform your operation.
To get selected option menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

About the errors:
*customlistadapter (android.app.activity list) in customlistadapter cannot be applied to (android.content.context)
in pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); ProgressDialog(android.app.activity list) in ProgressDialogcannot be applied to (com.kemo.editedtutorial.sliderfragments.MoviesListFragment)*

Instead of passing **this** pass `getActivity()` as both of them are expecting `context` as argument value which is of activity but you are passing it as of Fragment. so either you can pass `getActivity()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to solve this error
Hope this will help you

Comment: This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
Variables, method parameters and return values marked as Nullable or NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report possible NullPointerException errors.

Comment: More complex contracts can be defined using Contract annotation, for example:
Contract("_, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 
The inspection can be configured to use custom Nullable
NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)

Comment: that is what I got when I added `((MainActivity)(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));`

Comment: I also have this error: "customlistadapter (android.app.activity list<Movies>) in customlistadapter cannot be applied to (com.kemo.editedtutorial.sliderfragments.MoviesListFragment; list<Movies>)". I also get the same arror for the     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding the inspection error you are getting for `((MainActivity)(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().setBac‌​kgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. One more question - if I use  `ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar!=null) {
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        }` then I don't have to use `((MainActivity)(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));`?

Thanks again

Comment: obviously, you don't have to use.

Answer (score 4):

**1. cannot resolve method findViewById(?)**

You have written this code in `onCreateView()` after `return` statement.

First `Inflate` your `view`, do necessary operations on that and then return that `view`

also use `view.findViewById()`

**2. cannot resolve symbol list**
**3. cannot resolve symbol menu**

here your `R.java` has not getting generated due to some mistakes in `drawable` or your `layout`.

**4. cannot resolve getActionBar**

you are in `Fragment` and `getActionBar` is method from `Activity` so you need to call` getActivity().getActionBar()

**5. cannot resolve method getMenuInflater()**
**6. method does not override method from its superclass**

you are in `Fragment` and `getMenuInflater()` is method from `Activity` so you need to call `getActivity().getMenuInflater()`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    getActivity().getMenuInflater()....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                        ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view .findViewById(R.id.list);
    //cannot resolve method findViewById(?) and cannot resolve symbol list
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
    //cannot resolve getActionBar
return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

use:

(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
etc

Comment: I did this: `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playdates, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);` but still get the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, that you execute command `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false)`, return result immediately and then trying to find appropriate views.

View, that is result of inflating, contains all its children, so the same view must be used to find them later on. Instead of just `findViewById` you should use

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call return method at the end of the onCreateView() method because if you call return method at the below of onCreateView() then View class is unable to find any id .So, you may use like this:-

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                        ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View  v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //cannot resolve method findViewById(?) and cannot resolve symbol list
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

return v;
}
```

Comment: please try this  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda, null);  to inflate layout.